# How to send "multiple" extra parameters on a link/button_to_remote call?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

In this example,

```
<%=button_to_remote "Get Related Users", {:url => { :action => 'get_related_users' }, 
          :update => 'result',:with=>"'someVal=3'"} %>
```

If I have to send one more key/value pair [someVal2=5], what will the :with look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docs say

> A JavaScript expression specifying the
>   parameters for the XMLHttpRequest. Any
>   expressions should return a valid URL
>   query string.

so I imagine that you would do something like

```
<%=button_to_remote "Get Related Users", {:url => { :action => 'get_related_users' }, 
          :update => 'result',:with=>"'someVal=3&someVal2=5'"} %>
```